# Get query from Visual PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

On powerBI, we can easily filter data with joined table for example, but I would like to get the query behind the result, it's possible to extract the query DAX from exemple from a visual ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, first go on View->Performance analyzer

[image]

Then click start recording and refresh visuals:

[image]

And there you have the Copy query button which contains the underlying DAX query.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, that's work, but when I copy paste the dax query on a new measure I have many errors, it's not compatible ?

Comment: For the most part you have to adjust it, cause the DAX query executed for each visualization will return a table and it's a query ran directly against the model.